# Delete Prefilled Text in Input When no Text Is Typed

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

I want there to be text displayed inside of the text field, but when you type something, the text disappears. Kind of the input field to add tags in StackOverflow:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use placeholder attribute.

```css
input {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Enter something...."/>
```